# java.net.SocketException: Too many open files in cxf

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a `soap` client by `Apache CXF`.

Sometimes I catch a exception when I want connect to server:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at $Proxy81.transferFunds(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: SocketException invoking http://10.20.112.30:40001/Service/JJMService?wsdl: Too many open files
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor418.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:2107) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2092) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:697) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255) ~[cxf-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:516) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:447) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:577) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:2003) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1955) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42) ~[cxf-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69) ~[cxf-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2023) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

I construct proxy client by following code:

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setAddress("http://10.20.112.30:40001/Service/JJMService?wsdl");
factoryBean.setServiceClass(Service.class);
Service proxyObject = (Service) factoryBean.create();
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit)ClientProxy.getClient(proxyObject).getConduit();
httpConduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
httpConduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(5000);
```

This code call once , means `proxyObject` is singleton.

I have tow question:

1. Above Exception occurred at Server or my client?
2. What solution for this problem?

**EDITED:**

With above snippet code I create a client instance to `Service` interface, then for call methods I call simply `Service` interface method, as following:

```
proxyObject.notifyAccountStatement(acountNumber);
```

*Note for call `Service` interface is I call concurrent on a instanse (`proxyObject`)*

My `Apache CXF` version is : **2.3.3**

Comment: The exception is on your client. Too many open files usually means too much open connections. Check you are closing all connections

Comment: @pedrofb What is the way of close connection in `Apache CXF`?

Comment: Basically consuming response. WebClient does it for you. Please include your client code invoking web service and indicate CXF version

Comment: I edited original question by new data.Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I never used CXF reusing 'proxyObject'. Have you tried to use a new one on each call? Also, CXF version is a bit old. The problems appears with 3.1?

Comment: @pedrofb no, don't test with another version of `CXF`. Have benefit it? Also I test that create a `proxyObject` on any service call is weight and spend several second.